# How to get a boolean result SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an sql query which would return the imageId, total number of likes this image has, and also a boolean of whether or not the current user likes that image.

What I have so far is:

```
Select i.imageId, count(l.likeId) as numOfLikes
FROM Images as i LEFT JOIN Likes as l USING (imageID)
WHERE i.userId = '16'
GROUP BY i.imageId
ORDER BY i.dateCreated DESC
```

Which works great for the imageIds and total number of likes for each image. I'm not sure tho how I'd be able to determine whether or not the user likes that image within the same query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just check if the number of likes is greater than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
Select i.imageId, count(l.likeId) as numOfLikes
, count(likes2.*) LikesByUser
FROM Images as i LEFT JOIN Likes as l USING (imageID)
left join likes likes2 using (imageID, UserId)
WHERE i.userId = '16'
GROUP BY i.imageId
ORDER BY i.dateCreated DESC
```

LikesByUser should be 0 or 1.